Adding a clause to UNION query in MySQL causes new rows to appear in an earlier clause
I have created a query to consolidate SAT, PSAT10 and PSAT89 student records from different source tables into single records of longitudinal data.  I have WITH statements to excerpt and filter the SAT, PSAT10 and PSAT89 records, and a UNION statement to join them up.  The three clauses in the UNION pull a) records for students with SAT scores, including any PSAT10 or PSAT89 data they also have, b) records for students with PSAT10 scores but no SAT scores, including any PSAT89 data they also have, and c) records for students with only PSAT89 scores.  Each clause labels the records it contributes to the result set in the "source" column.
If I run the query with the UNION containing a) and b), I get a large number of records labeled as "sat" and a small number labeled as "psat10", as expected.  The problem is that when I add the third SELECT statement to the UNION (labeled as EVIL CLAUSE!!! in the code sample), it adds a small number of rows labeled as "psat89", and triggers the addition of a TON of new rows labeled as "psat10", all of which have blank SAT-related columns.  I cannot comprehend how adding a third clause to a UNION query can trigger the inclusion of additional rows in the second clause.  I would think I was going nuts but a coworker has witnessed this and she has confirmed I'm not hallucinating.
    with `sat` AS (
        SELECT `sat_msds_identities`.`identity_id` `sat_identity_id`, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `sat_msds_identities`.`identity_id` ORDER BY `sat_records`.`LATEST_SAT_DATE` DESC) AS `sat_row_number`,
        `sat_records`.`id` `sat_id`,
        `sat_records`.`SECONDARY_ID` `sat_UIC`,
        `sat_records`.`NAME_LAST` `sat_last`,
        `sat_records`.`NAME_FIRST` `sat_first`,
        `sat_records`.`BIRTH_DATE` `sat_birthdate`,
        `sat_records`.`LATEST_SAT_DATE` `latest_sat_date`,
        `sat_records`.`LATEST_SAT_TOTAL` `latest_sat_total`,
        `sat_records`.`LATEST_SAT_EBRW` `latest_sat_ebrw`,
        `sat_records`.`LATEST_SAT_MATH_SECTION` `latest_sat_math`
        FROM `sat_records`
        LEFT JOIN `sat_msds_identities`
        ON `sat_records`.`id` = `sat_msds_identities`.`sat_id`
        WHERE `sat_records`.`LATEST_SAT_GRADE` = 6 /* 11th Grade */
    ),
    
    `psat10` AS (
        SELECT `psat10_msds_identities`.`identity_id` `psat10_identity_id`, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `psat10_msds_identities`.`identity_id` ORDER BY `psat10_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_DATE` DESC) AS `psat10_row_number`,        
        `psat10_records`.`id` `psat10_id`,
        `psat10_records`.`SECONDARY_ID` `psat10_UIC`,
        `psat10_records`.`NAME_LAST` `psat10_last`,
        `psat10_records`.`NAME_FIRST` `psat10_first`,
        `psat10_records`.`BIRTH_DATE` `psat10_birthdate`,
        `psat10_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_DATE` `latest_psat10_date`,
        `psat10_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_TOTAL` `latest_psat10_total`,
        `psat10_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_EBRW` `latest_psat10_ebrw`,
        `psat10_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_MATH_SECTION` `latest_psat10_math`
        FROM `psat10_records`
        LEFT JOIN `psat10_msds_identities`
        ON `psat10_records`.`id` = `psat10_msds_identities`.`psat10_id`
        WHERE `psat10_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_GRADE` = 5 /* 10th Grade */
    ),
    
    `psat89` AS (
        SELECT `psat89_msds_identities`.`identity_id` `psat89_identity_id`, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `psat89_msds_identities`.`identity_id` ORDER BY `psat89_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_DATE` DESC) AS `psat89_row_number`,        
        `psat89_records`.`id` `psat89_id`,
        `psat89_records`.`SECONDARY_ID` `psat89_UIC`,
        `psat89_records`.`NAME_LAST` `psat89_last`,
        `psat89_records`.`NAME_FIRST` `psat89_first`,
        `psat89_records`.`BIRTH_DATE` `psat89_birthdate`,
        `psat89_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_DATE` `latest_psat89_date`,
        `psat89_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_TOTAL` `latest_psat89_total`,
        `psat89_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_EBRW` `latest_psat89_ebrw`,
        `psat89_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_MATH_SECTION` `latest_psat89_math`
        FROM `psat89_records`
        LEFT JOIN `psat89_msds_identities`
        ON `psat89_records`.`id` = `psat89_msds_identities`.`psat89_id`
        WHERE `psat89_records`.`LATEST_PSAT_GRADE` = 4 /* 9th Grade */
    ),
    
    `test_history` as(
        SELECT DISTINCT 'sat' `source`,
        `sat_identity_id` `identity_id`, 
        `sat_UIC` `UIC`,
        `sat_last` `last`,
        `sat_first` `first`,
        `sat_birthdate` `birthdate`,
        `sat_id`,
        `latest_sat_date`,
        `sat_row_number`,
        `latest_sat_total`,
        `latest_sat_ebrw`,
        `latest_sat_math`,
        `psat10_id`,
        `latest_psat10_date`, 
        `psat10_row_number`,
        `latest_psat10_total`,
        `latest_psat10_ebrw`,
        `latest_psat10_math`,
        `psat89_id`,
        `latest_psat89_date`,
        `psat89_row_number`,    
        `latest_psat89_total`,
        `latest_psat89_ebrw`,
        `latest_psat89_math`
        FROM `sat`
        LEFT JOIN `psat10`
        ON `sat`.`sat_identity_id` = `psat10`.`psat10_identity_id`
        LEFT JOIN `psat89`
        ON `sat`.`sat_identity_id` = `psat89`.`psat89_identity_id`
    
        UNION
        SELECT 'psat10' `source`,
        `psat10_identity_id`, 
        `psat10_UIC`,
        `psat10_last`,
        `psat10_first`,
        `psat10_birthdate`,
        `sat_id`,
        `latest_sat_date`,
        `sat_row_number`,
        `latest_sat_total`,
        `latest_sat_ebrw`,
        `latest_sat_math`,
        `psat10_id`,
        `latest_psat10_date`, 
        `psat10_row_number`,
        `latest_psat10_total`,
        `latest_psat10_ebrw`,
        `latest_psat10_math`,
        `psat89_id`,
        `latest_psat89_date`,
        `psat89_row_number`,
        `latest_psat89_total`,
        `latest_psat89_ebrw`,
        `latest_psat89_math`
        FROM `psat10`
        LEFT JOIN `sat`
        ON `psat10`.`psat10_identity_id` = `sat`.`sat_identity_id`
        LEFT JOIN `psat89`
        ON `psat10`.`psat10_identity_id` = `psat89`.`psat89_identity_id`
        WHERE `sat_id` IS NULL AND `latest_psat10_date` NOT LIKE '2024%'
    
    /* EVIL CLAUSE!!! */
        UNION
        SELECT 'psat89' `source`, 
        `psat89_identity_id`, 
        `psat89_UIC`,
        `psat89_last`,
        `psat89_first`,
        `psat89_birthdate`,
        `sat_id`,
        `latest_sat_date`,
        `sat_row_number`,
        `latest_sat_total`,
        `latest_sat_ebrw`,
        `latest_sat_math`,
        `psat10_id`,
        `latest_psat10_date`, 
        `psat10_row_number`,
        `latest_psat10_total`,
        `latest_psat10_ebrw`,
        `latest_psat10_math`,
        `psat89_id`,
        `latest_psat89_date`,
        `psat89_row_number`,    
        `latest_psat89_total`,
        `latest_psat89_ebrw`,
        `latest_psat89_math`
        FROM `psat89`
        LEFT JOIN `sat`
        ON `psat89`.`psat89_identity_id` = `sat`.`sat_identity_id`
        LEFT JOIN `psat10`
        ON `psat89`.`psat89_identity_id` = `psat10`.`psat10_identity_id`
        WHERE `sat_id` IS NULL AND `psat10_id` IS NULL AND `latest_psat89_date` NOT LIKE '2024%' AND `latest_psat89_date` NOT LIKE '2023%'
        ORDER BY `last`, `first`, `identity_id`
    /* END EVIL CLAUSE!!! */
    
        )
        
        SELECT `test_history`.* 
        FROM `test_history`;

If anybody can see anything odd about the structure of this query which would result in this weird behavior I am all ears.

I think it unlikely that the result you are seeing is caused by the 3rd union but that's going to be difficult to prove either way without data - do you have a sample you can publish? If not I will attempt to reproduce but it will take some time..

I can't reproduce - please review https://dbfiddle.uk/-S9PcHxX and if your model is different post a fiddle..nb the order by first and last name doesn't appear to be helpful

@P.Salmon  I respect your skepticism, and greatly appreciate your efforts, but the additional records literally appear from nowhere prefixed by 'psat10' when I add that third clause, which should only add new records prefixed by 'psat89'.  I am exceptionally confused.

can I get my hands on the data? Are these big tables? can they be published? or are they public domain? where are you running this query (mysql command line, mysqlworkbench or something else)

change the literals for source to 'first-query', 'second-query' and 'third-query' this way there can be no doubt as to where the rows come from see: https://dbfiddle.uk/gx7Ohiyi

I would start to debug this by running the query in mysql replacing SELECT test_history.*  FROM test_history`;  with select source,count(*) from test_history group by source, this would avoid any LIMITs (default or otherwise) imposed by anything else in play. running this with the first 2 joined queries and comparing the results to the the result of the 3 joined queries.

If the results differ for psat10 I would then push results of the 2 join query (as a result of SELECT test_history.*  FROM test_history`; ) into a table and the results of a 3 join query into another table then match them to identify what's popped in to psat10 and what the extra rows look like.
